# Update user data when something has changed on another client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, server

I make a clone of Discord on Next.js and when, for example, I delete the server, another client still sees this server and can use it until the page reloads. I tried the discord web app and everything seemed to change in real time.
Maybe there is a way to somehow notify all users about the change and reload the page

I thought about web sockets, but I would have to do everything on them and it seems to me that this is not a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for your issue is to use a WebSocket by triggering/listening to events and handling your logic based on it.

I used to face this issue, but I was really confused about WebSocket since it needs a real server to work with. I used [Pusher](https://pusher.com) to handle WebSockets without a server for some time, but I eventually switched to another approach, which involves fetching data on the client with a refresh interval using [SWR](https://swr.vercel.app). `@vercel/swr` provides hooks to fetch/mutate data on the client side with a wide range of options that make it powerful.

How does that work? Simply fetch the data and set a `refreshInterval` for a short time, like a minute. Whenever the interval elapses, it re-fetches the data and updates the rendered data by adding, editing, or removing.

```js
"use client"

import useSWR from "swr"

function Servers() {
  const { data: servers, isLoading, error } = useSWR("key-for-caching", fetcherFn, {
    refreshInterval: 60_000
  })
  // ...
}
```

**Note**: [`@tanstack/react-query`](https://tanstack.com/query/latest) is a good equivalent too.

This worked well for my use cases, but you should know that this is not real-time data in the literal sense. It depends on your use cases; if data can be updated within a minute or whatever the `refreshInterval` is, this is a good solution. If you need real-time updates, you'll have to use a WebSocket.

### Update:

Moving the fetching layer from the server to the client comes with its issues, As you know fetching on the client is not as fast as the server. so, to make your app look more powerful you should provide a fallback for the data until it's loaded:

```
<h2>{isLoading ? <Skeleton /> : server.name}</h2>
```

Or instead (that is what I do), Fetch the data first on the server (`page.tsx`), then pass the data to the client component as a prop. then set this data as a `fallbackData` to `useSWR`:

```js
"use client"

import useSWR from "swr"

function Servers({initialData}) {
  const { data: servers, isLoading, error } = useSWR("key-for-caching", fetcherFn, {
    refreshInterval: 60_000,
    fallbackData: initialData
  })
  // ...
}
```

This way, It will use the server data until the client is loaded.